# how can i convert time span to a double value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  TimeSpan totaldays = endtime.Subtract(starttime);
  double tdays = Convert.ToDouble(totaldays);
```

I m getting here error as

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

how can I get timespan value as a double type

Answer (score 11):

Just need to use the [`TimeSpan.TotalDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
TimeSpan totaldays = endtime.Subtract(starttime);
double tdays = totaldays.TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

being more simple

```
  double d=(endtime-starttime).totaldays;
```

worked for me.can reduce number of code lines.